# django link format words joined with hypens

Tags: python, django

href="http://www.torontolife.com/daily/daily-dish/restauranto/2010/03/10/best-new-restaurants-2010-james-chatto-names-five-honourable-mentions/">Best new restaurants 2010: honourable mentions

does django have built in mechanism to format links above
i mean words joined with hypens

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "words joined with hypens" thing you're talking about is known as a ***slug***.  It is a unique string identifier used to access a specific resource.

Django does provide support for using this type of resource-to-URL mapping.

- There is a built in `SlugField` which you can use to store the unique string for each resource
- Django's url routing scheme supports "accepting" slugs

To get started doing something like this, you're going to need to understand how the Django framework works overall.  I'd recommend checking out the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/).  It includes a full (and free) tutorial to get you started on how to use these types of things.

Answer (score 4):

At a lower level, Django provides a function to transform an arbitrary string into a slug:

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> print slugify('Hello, World!')
hello-world
```

And because `slugify` is a default template filter, you can always use this in your templates like so:

```
{{ foo.name|slugify }}
```